# GUI program to shred or wipe files with options to make sure they are unrecoverable?

Tags: software-recommendation, configuration, security, shredding

I have a quick question about file shredding. Is there any application with graphical interface capable of shredding files and folders?

I know bleachbit has that feature but there are no options or configurations and I really can't know if the files are unrecoverable or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest option I could find with your requirements is `nautilus-wipe`.

- Go to the Software Center, search for `nautilus-wipe`, and install it.

[image]

- After installing, you'll need to completely close Nautilus. The easiest way to do this is to log out and log back in.
- Open Nautilus, navigate to what you want to wipe, right-click on any file/folder to see the options `Wipe` and `Wipe Available Diskpace`
- If you click on wipe, you will see the following:

[image]

- You can configure the options (type of wipe, number of passes, etc.) by clicking on the Options triangle:

[image]

- Clicking `Wipe Available Diskspace` on any item or within empty space in Nautilus will offer to wipe free space on the that partition:

[image]

- Close Nautilus when done.

Comment: I'm correcting this. nautilus-wipe doesn't require root.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [bleachbit [image: Install bleachbit]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/bleachbit). It can be installed in the Software Center.

Answer (score 1):

I realize OP asked for a GUI option, nevertheless, for those needing a scriptable comand-line option, You may use 'shred' from GNU coreutils.

```
     man shred
```

for full details.