# GUI tool to securely overwrite whole hard drive

Tags: software-recommendation, gui, secure-erase

My friend has a Windows laptop that we want to totally wipe and then turn over to a hardware technician (whom we don't trust with the data on the hard drive.) I want to securely wipe, rather than encrypt the drive.

I'll boot Ubuntu from a pendrive. However, we would like to use a GUI solution. I've searched this site for that, but couldn't find what I was looking for.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Paerhaps this might be useful: http://askubuntu.com/q/139474/57576

Comment: @andrew.46 Will Bleachbit overwrite the whole drive?

Comment: Also, this is about wiping the whole drive, not individual files.

Comment: @kos those answers are all CLI. This question is for a GUI option.

Comment: I know, removed already. Apparently there used to be a GUI frontend to `dd` (`gdiskdump`), but it's not in the repositories anymore.

Comment: I suppose it'd be redundant to remark that using `dd` would be rather easy and wouldn't require downloading additional software. Combined with `pv` one would also get a nice progress bar.

Comment: I suppose I agree. But this friend is an old man who will not take kindly to CLI.

Comment: @kos I did find github for gdiskdump . . . Hasn't been updated since 4 years ago though

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**March 30 Edit**:

By looking at [this](https://askubuntu.com/q/751601/295286) question it turns out there exists a GUI front-end to dd called GDiskDump.

[image]

Installation is fairly simple ( steps i followed myself ):

1. `sudo apt-get install git`
2. `git clone https://github.com/screenfreeze/gdiskdump.git`
3. `cd gdiskdump/deb/  && sudo dpkg -i *.deb` ; you likely just want `dpkg -i gdiskdump_0.8-1_all.deb`

After the deb package has been installed and configured , run by calling `sudo gdiskdump`. Note , as every other disk utility , this one requires root privillege

**Original post**

You could overwrite your disk with zeros multiple times using `dd` command

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/XdY bs=1M && zenity --into --text="DONE"
```

where `X` and `Y` denominate the path to the device file of your drive (use `lsblk` to find out which one it is). Note, the `dd` commands takes a long time.

Alternatively you can perform the `shred` command:

```
shred -vfz -n 10 /dev/sdX
```

Note: here, the number of iterations is 10 which may be a bit of an overkill. Refer to `man shred` for the meaning of each flag.

The closest  tool for erasing a drive I found so far would be `nwipe`, which uses `ncurses` and which you can install using `sudo apt-get install nwipe`.

[image]

Comment: @Fiksdal not a lot of choices for GUI out there, so far I haven't seen any. You could put a GUI onto `dd` but that's essentially just "eye-candy" for what's already working without extra cr@p

Comment: I suppose I agree. But this friend is an old man who will not take kindly to CLI.

Answer (score 3):

Both gparted and KDE Partition manager have (or had) secure erase options.  They're buried in the menus, but they're there.  One (I don't recall which, and I'm away from my home computer at the moment) actually has some options on how thoroughly you want the overwrite done.

Another, probably more versatile option, is to download a (paid) copy of Parted Magic.  It's a complete OS (Linux based, of course) chock full of GUI disk management and repair tools, including a couple different secure erase options.  The developer had to start charging for the distro a couple years ago, but if you want a real secure erase and aren't finding what you need in gparted or KDE Partition Manager, Parted Magic for certain includes it and is likely worth the (fairly low) cost.