# Gdiskdump does not show harddrives, only partitions

Tags: gnome, dd

I can see partitions but not even one harddisk.

How can I see my harddisks and clone them?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Partitions are parts of hard drives, so technically it does show you your hard drive(s) layout. As for cloning, consider clonezilla or some similar tool. dd is simple but it's like a scalpel - if you're not careful ,youll cut off something you didn't want

Comment: There was GPT MBR conflict due to previous Windows 10 install in one of the disks. I fixed it but I still do not see a single "Harddrive" in Gdiskdump window. So what does Gdd mean with that term, since it shows partitions?

Comment: OK, so I went on to install gdiskdump myself from github, because apparently it is not in the official repositories.  It is of course odd that you don't have any output for "Harddrive" section, because it should show four device files : `/dev/sda` , `/dev/sdb` ,  `/dev/sdc` and `/dev/sdd`  . Here's example of what I have , 2 disks , 1 virtuall device http://imgur.com/xZJHPNG  . As for why ? No idea.

Answer (score 1):

Gdiskdump shows you have three HDDs: sdb, sdc, sdd.

also try gparted and parted.

To clone a drive and all partitions, including MBR or GPT:

BE CAREFUL with dd! You can easily make a mistake.

make sure its unmounted ( like when using a liveusb)

```
dd if=/dev/<device> of=filename.you.choose
```

To get a specific partition:

```
dd if=/dev/sdxn of=filename  where sdxn is something like sdb1 or sdc6
```

to restore:

```
dd if=your.filename of=/dev/device[partition#] ( e.g. /dev/sdb3)
```

Comment: Why is "Harddisks" list empty, since there clearly are disks?

Comment: @Ohto I don't know about this app, but the two I suggested are reliable. Some caveats: you must be root or use sudo with these commands; its quite possible to delete your main partition or to copy a smaller partition over a larger one; fdisk does not work with GPT or EFI disks, so use parted; use mount or df -h to find out whats mounted.